# floyd's cycle-finding algorithm while checks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

```
P=head;
Q=head->next;
while( (p!=null) && (q!=null) )
{
    if(p==q) exit(0); // loop detected
    P=p->next;
    q=(q->next)?(q->next->next):q->next;
}
```

[Floyd's Alogorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtjSC.jpg)

In the above code (asked in an exam), the question was to fill the `while` loop and the above was given as the solution

The while condition is `p!=NULL AND q!=NULL` but I have tried many test cases and found that `q!=NULL` suffices the algorithm but the answer is strictly `p=!NULL AND q!=null`

My question is when will ever the `q!=null` in the while condition create a problem and when is the `p!=NULL` ever needed?

**NOTE:** Since this is a algorithm based question please ignore the syntax problems...

Comment: Please don't base your questions on images stored externally. If the external image changes or goes down, your question won't make sense.

Comment: I've added the code from the image into the question. Please double check that it is accurate

Comment: @CDspace Good for you!

Comment: @Ami The question was in the First Posts Review Queue. Plus, if that is _exactly_ the code he tested, then I think I see the problem right away

Comment: @CDspace thnx for d help

Comment: @Lotus Not a problem. While you are waiting for an answer, feel free to head over to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). It should be useful for future questions.

Comment: (assuming C) The second line `Q=head->next;` will fail if `head` happens to be NULL (which is possible)

Comment: @wildplasser This came to my mind too, problem is that compiler will kill the program before gong to the while loop and even if we assume that it doesn't then the `q!=NULL` alone will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you're correct that it's possible to only check the ["hare" and not "tortoise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) (by you, `q` and not `p`) for being `NULL`, as if the list is acylic, `p` is never ahead of `q`.

The code in your question, though, besides that, has some minor problems. (It's annoying how it alternates between uppercase and lowercase, to begin with.) As wildplasser correctly notes, there's undefined behavior when `head == NULL`.

Here is a version utilizing your idea of checking only the hare:

```
p = q = head;
while(q != NULL) {
    if(p == q)
        return true;
    if(q->next == NULL)
        return false;
    p = p->next;
    q = q->next->next;
}
return false;
```

Comment: I too have the same kind of corrected code but just wanted to know if there is a condition where `q!=NULL` just doesn't fulfill the need for while loop and there is a immense need of `p!=NULL && q!=NULL`... this was a question from an exam.. so bear with the code

Comment: @Lotus Except for those minor points, I agree with your logic (wrote so in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since `q` is advancing along the list faster than `p`, it will *always* reach the end of the list first. The only way `p` will ever be null is if the list was empty to begin with.

The code is incorrect for an empty list, since it tries to access a null pointer. You can fix that easily:

```
P=head;
Q=head?head->next:null;
```